# Excel vba: setting a long variable for each object class dramatically increases execution time

Tags: vba, performance, excel, memory

I have a main sub that makes use of a `Client` class: creates an array with `100 000` `Clients` and loops over the array `100` times, each time setting a different random number to each `Client`.

```
Sub start()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim j As Long

    Dim clientsColl() As Client
    ReDim clientsColl(1 To 100000) As Client

    For j = 1 To 100000
        Set clientsColl(j) = New Client

        clientsColl(j).setClientName = "Client_" & j
    Next

    Dim clientCopy As Variant

    MsgBox ("simulations start")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
            clientCopy.setSimulationCount = 100
            clientCopy.generateRandom
        Next
    Next

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

However, this code takes different time to run, depending whether the line `clientCopy.setSimulationCount = 100` is commented out or not. If this line is commented out the code after the `simulations start` `MsgBox` takes `16 seconds` to run. However, if that line is not commented out and is executed the second loop takes `2 minute 35 seconds` to run.

Here's the inside of the `Client` class, the used `Let` property:

```
Private simulationCount As Long

Public Property Let setSimulationCount(value As Double)
    simulationCount = value
End Property

Private randomNumber As Double

Public Sub generateRandom()
    randomNumber = Rnd()
End Sub
```

So it simply puts number `100` inside each client. Why would it increase execution time nine-fold?

Comment: If your code works should be moved to another forum to be improved.

Comment: Any code can be made slow by repeating it often enough.  And it is not fast code.   Consider changing the argument type from Double to Long so you don't pay for two expensive floating point conversions.  Avoid Variant, use Client.

Comment: Hmm, Dim obj As Client = clientCopy inside the loop should always work.  Use For..To instead of For Each should always work.

Comment: Your comments are *very* misleading.  Please delete the inaccurate ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `clientCopy` as a `Variant`, which has to be resolved at run-time for each method invocation.  Please change to be of type `Client` and re-run your timings.

Ok, I have re-read the question and comments, to speed up the loop change it thus

```
Option Explicit

Sub start()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim j As Long

    Dim clientsColl() As Client
    ReDim clientsColl(1 To 100000) As Client

    For j = 1 To 100000
        Set clientsColl(j) = New Client

        clientsColl(j).setClientName = "Client_" & j
    Next

    'Dim clientCopy As Variant
    Dim clientCopy As Client

    MsgBox ("simulations start")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Dim lClientLoop As Long
        For lClientLoop = LBound(clientsColl) To UBound(clientsColl)
        'For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
            Set clientCopy = clientsColl(lClientLoop)
            clientCopy.setSimulationCount = 100
            clientCopy.generateRandom
        Next
    Next

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't use Client in loops with arrays. I can't use Collection because I tried it and it runs even slower.

Comment: @S Meaden You used `for` loop instead of `for each`. I've been advised thousands of times on this very forum that `for each` loops are much much faster and must be used instead of `for` even if it requeres use of `Variant`.

Comment: Besides my quesion isn't about the loop. My question is about why adding that particular line of code with `Long` variable increases execution time so much. Using `for` *might* help (though I'm not sure), but the question would still stand.

Comment: I do not believe "thousands of times", your exaggeration is telling.  Just try it.

Comment: A 32-bit Long being set in a class (allocated on the heap and accessed via interfaces) is always gonna be slower than an array of Longs on the stack.  Stop using classes if you're going to be running this "thousands of times".

Comment: @S Meaden You were right, I'm sorry. The execution time did fall a lot: from `20 secunds` to `2 seconds` and from `2 minutes 35 seconds` to `5 seconds`. If you edit the question I would change the vote, I shouldn't have downvoted it (I can't change the vote unless question was edited). I'm still curious of the nature behind this - now the difference between the cases is about `3 seconds`, while in my example the difference is `2 minutes`. That is insane.

Comment: I'm leaving this Q&A thread now.  Final advice, I really like OO but in your use case (with Monte Carlo simulations I presume) running millions of iteration then classes will add too much baggage to use code.  Just declare a bunch of module level arrays with the key data.

Comment: @S Meaden You mean baggage in terms of memory overhead? Because apart from that classes provide useful interface, and code-wise help to retain more structure. I'll try to follow the advice though. Thank you a lot anyways, I didn't think such execution time decrease was possible! It now will save a lot of trouble performance-wise.